# Git fast-import sequence of versions

Tags: git

I write a frontend to import versions from another VCS system (Surround SCM). I want to generate a file for each fast-import operation. These files shall be imported into a Git repository in a sequence. Finally the import shall be closed.

```
git init
git fast-import < 00001
git fast-import < 00002
git fast-import < final
```

The files look like these:

file 00001

```
blob
mark :1
data 2
A
commit refs/heads/master
mark :2
committer Harper <H> 1459858949 -0000
data 4
AAA
M 100644 :1 fileA
```

file 00002

```
blob
mark :1
data 2
B
commit refs/heads/master
mark :2
committer Harper <H> 1459858959 -0000
data 4
BBB
M 100644 :1 fileA
```

file final

```
reset revs/heads/master
done
```

(Keep in mind that line endings must be only LF, if you want to reproduce.)

I can import one of the files and finalize the repository. But I get an error if I try to fast-import more than one file:

> $ git fast-import < 00002 Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 168 bytes | 0
> bytes/s, done.
> warning: Not updating refs/heads/master (new tip 28fce368183882d873dbb39e86120786db4bc25f does not contain d3e2179d08e95ebf5b509cb544d4f84c7a03c8e7)

The sha1 IDs vary for each run.

How can I import a sequence of files to build a Git repository?

Comment: You've left out the `from` lines in the non-first files.

Comment: @torek What would be the argument for the `from` command?

Comment: Presumably `refs/heads/master` will work, but I haven't actually tried any of this. If you dump your marks out with each pass, you can load the old marks (but the you need to figure out how to make your marks unique). Ah, the documentation says: "The special case of restarting an incremental import from the current branch value should be written as: `from refs/heads/branch^0` ..."